# Unable to set correct Email Template for Mailchimp Campaign via Python API

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm unable to set correct Email template for Mailchimp Campign.

I'm picking the `Template_ID` from the browser URL like: [https://xxx.admin.mailchimp.com/email/templates/editor?id=`Template_ID`](https://xxx.admin.mailchimp.com/email/templates/editor?id=%60Template_ID%60).

Is it correct?

```
        campaign_data = dict(
            type='regular',
            recipients=dict(list_id="SEGMENT ID", segment_opts=dict(
                saved_segment_id=segment_id)),
            settings=dict(
                subject_line=subject_line,
                from_name='FROM_EMAIL',
                reply_to='REPLY_EMAIL',
                template_id=<Template_ID>
            ),
            content_type="multichannel"
        )
        campaign = client.campaigns.create(campaign_data)
```

With the Above code, Campaign is getting created but it is not able to set correct template.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? i too am unable to assign a template to a campaign that was built with the 'New Builder' - it works if the template was built with the 'Classic Builder' -

Comment: Just finished chat with MailChimp support, and they confirmed that the API does not support assigning a template_id to a campaign if the template was built using the "New Email Builder".